# regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*

Tags: python, backend, pytube

Im making small youtube playlist and video downloader.

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import Playlist

path = 'MY PATH'


def download_video(link, resolution, path):
    try:
        yt = YouTube(link, use_oauth=True, allow_oauth_cache=True)
        stream = yt.streams.get_by_resolution(resolution)
        print(f'Downloading , {stream.title}')
        stream.download(path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'oops! Error: {e}')


def download_playlist(link, resolution, path):
    try:
        playlist = Playlist(link)
        print('Downloading ', playlist.videos)
        for video in playlist.videos:
            video.streams.get_by_resolution(resolution).download(path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'oops! Error: {e}')


global_choise = input(
    'Hi! What do you want to download? playlist/video (1/2) >> ')

if global_choise == '1':
    link = input('Enter URL of playlist >> ')
    resolution = input(
        'Enter resolution(144p, 240p, 360p, 720p, 1080p...) >> ')
    download_video(link, resolution, path)

elif global_choise == '2':
    link = input('Enter URL of video >> ')
    resolution = input(
        'Enter resolution(144p, 240p, 360p, 720p, 1080p...) >> ')
    download_video(link, resolution, path)
```

But when i want to download playlist, i got this error:

```
regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*
```

i tried to update pytube, but nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide the whole traceback so we don't guess where the error comes from. And ideally please provide [mre].

Comment: What links are you supplying? The error suggests the YouTube URL is invalid. Are they shortened `youtu.be` links by chance?